# how does intern() helps in improving uncertainty and performance?

Tags: java

The intern method returns the canonical form of the string,  can it be different or the same as the string itself. Is it helpful in boosting the performance or just removes uncertainty?

Comment: There are over200 questions on this site about `intern()`: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+String.intern did you really need to add another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intern() improves performance by reducing the number of duplicate strings.  This reduces memory consumption but more importantly improve use of the caches. (The caches being *much* smaller than you main memory)

However, using it directly can have performance problems if you place too many string in this pool (not something a normal program would do, but you could write a program to do so)  This is because it is expensive to add strings to the pool O(N) not O(log N) as you might assume and even more expensive to clean up.  In java 7 the string literal pool was moved to the heap to reduce the impact of large String literal pools but I would still suggest you use it sparingly if at all.

Comment: +1 Can you add a bit more on how O(N) arises?

Comment: I don't know enough about the internals, but when I have tested the time taken to perform an `intern()`, in Java 6, it has been literal with then number of Strings added. (I added 100K to 1 million strings, much more than would normally be there)  It could be a 16-bit hash map which degenerates into linked lists for all I know.

Answer (score 1):

`intern` doesn't change the string at all; it just allocates the memory for it in the special-purpose **constant pool**, which is not part of the regular heap (it is in the *permanent generation*). Performance is improved only indirectly: if you know you are comparing two interned strings, you can reliably use `==` instead of `equals`.

Comment: No, you should NEVER use == on a string. Because if someone changes one of them to be non-interned your code will break. String equals() checks for reference equality anyway, so its not even an optimisation.

Comment: @Visage such dogmatic imperatives are never fruitful. If I write a piece of code that has full control over the strings it uses for map keys, for example, there won't be a "someone" to mess with them. Calling `equals` incurs the cost of dynamic dispatch, at least until it gets inlined by the JIT, which you have no control over.

Comment: The string literal pool was moved to the heap in Java 7.

Comment: @PeterLawrey So if nobody is referencing a literal, it is subject to GC? On the flip side, all the literals contribute to the total load on  the GC, which needs to check their reachability. There's a good chance that this actually makes sense today as opposed to 1996, or whatever year it was that the original String was designed.

Comment: You are correct on both concerns.  Strings can be cleaned up but it is very expensive AFAIK.  It you just add random Strings to the literal pool all day you won't run out of memory in Java 5.0 (I suspect in earlier versions you would)  Placing it in the heap reduces the cost when a String needs to be clearer, but increases the cost for regular GCs.

Answer (score 0):

When you call intern method on a string, it will check whether string pool has that string.If it exists, it will return a reference to that string, otherwise a new string will be added to pool.Performance can be improved since you can use == instead of equals(== check is faster since it will only compare the object address rather than its content), but I strongly recommend not to use == to compare strings.